# Calling a function with arguments in a method scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I have functions that takes 2 Ints and returns 1 Int:

```
val sub : (Int, Int) => Int = (x,y) => x - y
val mul : (Int, Int) => Int = (x,y) => x * y
```

How will I create a method that accepts the above type. I tried:

```
  def test(f:(Int,Int) => Int) : Unit = {
    val a = f
    println(a)
  }
```

Which does not seem to work.

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: I dont understand exactly what doesn't work? is it not compiling or what is your output supposed to be? What are you basing your "Not working" on?

Comment: This works just fine, what is the problem?

Comment: It works just fine

Comment: did you just forget to give val a = f(3,1) params so that it will execute? because what you have is correct you still need to execute the function that you have passed in

Comment: Hello guys, thank you all for the help, I should have been specific in my description. I did not know how to call the function. Now after reading the replies, I figured I was not calling the function correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess by "Does not seem to work.", you mean you're trying to call the function and expected an output in the `println`.

The function works as designed. It's just not the way you probably hoped it will work...

So this for instance will not work:

```
scala> test(sub(5, 3))
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: (Int, Int) => Int
       test(sub(5, 3))
```

But you can modify `test()` slightly:

```
scala> def test(f:(Int,Int) => Int, x: Int, y: Int) : Unit = {
     |     val a = f(x, y)
     |     println(a)
     | }
test: (f: (Int, Int) => Int, x: Int, y: Int)Unit
```

And call it with the params:

```
scala> test(sub, 5, 3)
2

scala> test(mul, 5, 3)
15
```